# Google API requested! - Displayed in firebase serve

Tags: firebase

I have trouble authenticating my Google API and have no clue how to solve it. I want to get my Firestore document by using the REST api but it gives me no data at all in postman.

```
http://localhost:5000/<project-id>/us-central1/api/todos
```

I have tried this in my project dir and using cmd.

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/functions/util/apikey.json"
```

But still no changes.

Below is my terminal that shows the warning.

[image]